# Android loop through nested hashmaps

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to create nested hashmaps to save user previous jobs like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> firstJob = new HashMap<String, String>();
    firstJob.put("Title","instructor");
    firstJob.put("From","2008");
    firstJob.put("To","2010");
    firstJob.put("At","Company1");

    HashMap<String, String> secondJob = new HashMap<String, String>();
    secondJob.put("Title","PHP developer");
    secondJob.put("From","2010");
    secondJob.put("To","2013");
    secondJob.put("At","Company2");

    HashMap<String, String> thirdJob = new HashMap<String, String>();
    thirdJob.put("Title","PHP developer");
    thirdJob.put("From","2013");
    thirdJob.put("To","2018");
    thirdJob.put("At","Company3");

    HashMap<String, HashMap> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
    myHashMap.put("first", firstJob);
    myHashMap.put("second", secondJob);
    myHashMap.put("third", thirdJob);
```

And now I want to loop thorugh it to display it in rows first job then second job etc...

```
    String txt = "";

    Iterator it = myHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        txt += pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue() + "\n";
        d.setText(txt);
    }
```

The pair.getValue() has the whole hashmap value {From=2008, At=Company1, To=2010, Title=instructor} and now I want to iterate it to display it as list

```
Position:instructor
Started:2008
Ended:2010
At:Company1
```

Then the next job etc ... How can I loop through these inner hashmaps?

If this is not the best way to do it so what's the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you doing that instead of a model/list?

Comment: still learning so i don't know what a model/list is?

Comment: You already have code that loops through a hashmap. Whats stopping you from using that same code to loop through an inner hashmap?

Comment: You could fairly easily use json for for something like this

Comment: This can be simplified by creating a class named like `JobDescription` with all fields `Title`, `From` etc and then just create a `List` of these objects. Then you can iterate over that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class, or model, like this...
I also advise you to change the variable name. Dont use `title, from, to, at` as this can get confusing in your code as you use them. Be more creative.

```
public class ModelExample {

        String title;
        String from;
        String to;
        String at;

        public ModelExample(String title, String from, String to, String at) {
            this.title = title;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.at = at;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getFrom() {
            return from;
        }
        public void setFrom(String from) {
            this.from = from;
        }
        public String getTo() {
            return to;
        }
        public void setTo(String to) {
            this.to = to;
        }
        public String getAt() {
            return at;
        }
        public void setAt(String at) {
            this.at = at;
        }
}
```

Create a List and insert them in.

```
List<ModelExample> model = new ArrayList<ModelExample>();
model.add(new ModelExample("instructor", "2008", "2010", "Company1"));
model.add(new ModelExample("PHP Dev", "2010", "2013", "Company 3"));
model.add(new ModelExample("PHP Dev 2", "2013", "2018", "Company3"));
```

Then you can loop through this list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + model.get(i).getTitle());
    System.out.println("From: " + model.get(i).getFrom());
    System.out.println("At: " + model.get(i).getAt());
    System.out.println("To: " + model.get(i).getTo());
    System.out.println("\n------------------\n");
}
```

This will print out the following..

```
Title: instructor
From: 2008
At: Company1
To: 2010

------------------

Title: PHP Dev
From: 2010
At: Company 3
To: 2013

------------------

Title: PHP Dev 2
From: 2013
At: Company3
To: 2018

------------------
```